# Regex trim leading whitespace

Tags: regex

How do I trim the leading whitespace?

```
[^-;]style=".*?"
```

will select this correctly, but it includes the leading space. 
How do I remove it?

```
{{col.displ style="{cursor: col.cursor}" ng ayName}}
// selection: ' style="{cursor: col.cursor}"'
```

Comment: Which language or environment are you using this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative look behind:

```
(?<![;-])style="[^"]*"
```

The regex `(?<![;-])` means "the preceeding character must not be a `;` or a `-`", but doesn't capture it: Look arounds are non capturing ie zero-width.

Comment: Geat ! `(?<![-])style="[^"]*"` was exactly what I needed ! thx

Answer (score 0):

This includes anything that is NOT `-` or `;`:

```
[^-;]
```

You want to screen out spaces you can add a space:

```
[^-; ]
```

To screen out all white space characters you can add:

```
[^-;\s]
```

Here's a [good reference for REGEX](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

If you're only trying to capture a phrase starting with the word "style", then there's no reason for the match at all.

Then look for anything inside the quotes that is not a quote:

```
style=\"[^\"]+\"
```

I've added escape characters since it's not clear what app or language you're including this code in.

Answer (score -1):

try this pattern:

```
style=["][^"]+["]
```

or in your pattern you can do:

```
[^-; ]style=["][^"]+["]
```

Comment: -1 The first regex allows the preceding chat to be ; or -, which the OP doesn't want. The second one captures the space. Neither work.